# Find and Replace Value in a table

Tags: vba, ms-word

Here is the table I am working on to find all "Test 1" in the document and replace by "Test 2".

[image]

```vb
Sub Macro2()

    Dim x As String
    Dim y As String

    x = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows(2).Cells(2).Range.Text
    y = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows(2).Cells(3).Range.Text
 
    MsgBox x
    MsgBox y
  
    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
        .Text = x
        .ClearFormatting
        .Forward = True
        .Execute
        If .Found = True Then .Replacement.Text = y
    End With
 
End Sub
```

The value remains the same.

I have two Msgbox to locate my the text selection, I am sure I am locating the cell correctly.

Comment: A problem with table cells is that they contain two structural characters that will be picked up by `Range.Text`: a paragraph mark (ANSI 13) and an end-of-cell marker (ANSI 7). That's probably why your code is not yielding the expected result. Test this: change x = "Test 1" and y = "Test 2" - to search the terms literally. If that works then we can look at trimming the unwanted characters.

Comment: Yes. It works when I test the term literally.

Comment: Did my Answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

I've taken the liberty of "tightening" your code a bit to make it more efficient and easier to read, by declaring objects for `ActiveDocument` and `Tables(1)`.

Since it also appears you want to do a simple Find/Replace I changed `.Execute` to do a replacement. But if your code is actually more complex, then you should, of course, retain the `If` you have in your original code.

I also added a function I use that cuts off the ANSI 13 and ANSI 7 characters from the end of the text returned by a cell Range. When you ran your code you may have noticed the black dot under "Test 1" or "Test 2" in the `MsgBox`? This is the ANSI 7, and the vertical spacing between the text and the dot is the paragraph mark (ANSI 13). These disappear when the function is used, and in my test, the replacement was successful.

```
Sub FindReplaceInTable()    
    Dim x As String
    Dim y As String
    Dim doc As word.Document
    Dim tbl As word.Table

    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    Set tbl = doc.Tables(1)
    x = TrimCellText(tbl.Rows(2).Cells(2).Range)
    y = TrimCellText(tbl.Rows(2).Cells(3).Range)

    'MsgBox x
    'MsgBox y

    With doc.content.Find
     .Text = x
     .ClearFormatting
     .Forward = True
     .Replacement.Text = y
     .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub

Function TrimCellText(r As word.Range) As String
    Dim sLastChar As String
    Dim sCellText As String

    sCellText = r.Text
    sLastChar = Right(sCellText, 1)
    Do While sLastChar = Chr(7) Or sLastChar = Chr(13)
        sCellText = Left(sCellText, Len(sCellText) - 1)
        sLastChar = Right(sCellText, 1)
    Loop
    TrimCellText = sCellText
End Function
```